# Java while loop randomRect method

Tags: java

So I'm studying for my final exam on practice.it and came across this problem that seems fairly easy but the output isn't what I need it to be. I think it has something to do with fence posting or the way I'm resetting count and/or max. The prompt was to write a method that continuously finds the area of two randomly generated numbers until 4 consecutive areas in ascending order are outputted. My problem is occurring because which ever way I change my code, either the tested output doesn't match up because it stops at count = 3, or after an amount of numbers is generated, count = 4 then it stops the loop, but because count was reset to 0, it printed 5 areas.

```
public static void randomRects(){
    Random r = new Random();
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;

    while(count<3){ // or < 4, both cause a problem either at the beginning or end of testing
        int w = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int h = r.nextInt(10) + 1;

        int area = w*h;
        if(area>max){
            count++;
        }else{
            count = 0;
        }
        max = area;
        System.out.println("w: " + w + ", " + "h: " + h + ", " + "area: " + area);
    }
    System.out.println("Four rectangles of increasing area.");
}
```

Comment: Cause you want to print out rectangle in ascending, I think you just need to move 2 lines (max assignment and print function) into the `if` body, then you don't need `else` anymore

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is correct. The way you are printing the results is confusing you. I suggest storing the results in an array and print the array after the `while` loop terminates.

Note that in the below code, the `print` inside the `while` loop is for debugging purposes only and can be safely removed.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Proj2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int count = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int[] as = new int[4];
        while (count < 4) {
            int w = r.nextInt(1, 11);
            int h = r.nextInt(1, 11);
            int a = w * h;
            if (a > max) {
                as[count++] = a;
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
            }
            System.out.printf("w = %d , h = %d , a = %d , max = %d , count = %d%n", w, h, a, max, count);
            max = a;
        }
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        System.out.println("Four rectangles of increasing area.");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(as));
    }
}
```

Output from a sample run of the above code:

```
w = 2 , h = 10 , a = 20 , max = 0 , count = 1
w = 6 , h = 4 , a = 24 , max = 20 , count = 2
w = 1 , h = 2 , a = 2 , max = 24 , count = 0
w = 5 , h = 9 , a = 45 , max = 2 , count = 1
w = 1 , h = 8 , a = 8 , max = 45 , count = 0
w = 10 , h = 10 , a = 100 , max = 8 , count = 1
w = 2 , h = 8 , a = 16 , max = 100 , count = 0
w = 4 , h = 10 , a = 40 , max = 16 , count = 1
w = 7 , h = 5 , a = 35 , max = 40 , count = 0
w = 1 , h = 6 , a = 6 , max = 35 , count = 0
w = 5 , h = 9 , a = 45 , max = 6 , count = 1
w = 7 , h = 7 , a = 49 , max = 45 , count = 2
w = 2 , h = 4 , a = 8 , max = 49 , count = 0
w = 6 , h = 2 , a = 12 , max = 8 , count = 1
w = 2 , h = 8 , a = 16 , max = 12 , count = 2
w = 2 , h = 1 , a = 2 , max = 16 , count = 0
w = 9 , h = 3 , a = 27 , max = 2 , count = 1
w = 1 , h = 2 , a = 2 , max = 27 , count = 0
w = 10 , h = 2 , a = 20 , max = 2 , count = 1
w = 10 , h = 5 , a = 50 , max = 20 , count = 2
w = 6 , h = 2 , a = 12 , max = 50 , count = 0
w = 4 , h = 4 , a = 16 , max = 12 , count = 1
w = 5 , h = 9 , a = 45 , max = 16 , count = 2
w = 8 , h = 3 , a = 24 , max = 45 , count = 0
w = 5 , h = 5 , a = 25 , max = 24 , count = 1
w = 1 , h = 7 , a = 7 , max = 25 , count = 0
w = 3 , h = 5 , a = 15 , max = 7 , count = 1
w = 8 , h = 3 , a = 24 , max = 15 , count = 2
w = 9 , h = 7 , a = 63 , max = 24 , count = 3
w = 8 , h = 7 , a = 56 , max = 63 , count = 0
w = 6 , h = 9 , a = 54 , max = 56 , count = 0
w = 7 , h = 1 , a = 7 , max = 54 , count = 0
w = 3 , h = 7 , a = 21 , max = 7 , count = 1
w = 1 , h = 10 , a = 10 , max = 21 , count = 0
w = 1 , h = 4 , a = 4 , max = 10 , count = 0
w = 1 , h = 7 , a = 7 , max = 4 , count = 1
w = 8 , h = 2 , a = 16 , max = 7 , count = 2
w = 8 , h = 5 , a = 40 , max = 16 , count = 3
w = 1 , h = 8 , a = 8 , max = 40 , count = 0
w = 9 , h = 5 , a = 45 , max = 8 , count = 1
w = 10 , h = 5 , a = 50 , max = 45 , count = 2
w = 6 , h = 1 , a = 6 , max = 50 , count = 0
w = 10 , h = 8 , a = 80 , max = 6 , count = 1
w = 4 , h = 6 , a = 24 , max = 80 , count = 0
w = 9 , h = 2 , a = 18 , max = 24 , count = 0
w = 4 , h = 1 , a = 4 , max = 18 , count = 0
w = 10 , h = 2 , a = 20 , max = 4 , count = 1
w = 10 , h = 7 , a = 70 , max = 20 , count = 2
w = 5 , h = 2 , a = 10 , max = 70 , count = 0
w = 2 , h = 9 , a = 18 , max = 10 , count = 1
w = 4 , h = 2 , a = 8 , max = 18 , count = 0
w = 6 , h = 3 , a = 18 , max = 8 , count = 1
w = 2 , h = 2 , a = 4 , max = 18 , count = 0
w = 1 , h = 7 , a = 7 , max = 4 , count = 1
w = 3 , h = 7 , a = 21 , max = 7 , count = 2
w = 4 , h = 2 , a = 8 , max = 21 , count = 0
w = 3 , h = 5 , a = 15 , max = 8 , count = 1
w = 4 , h = 8 , a = 32 , max = 15 , count = 2
w = 1 , h = 9 , a = 9 , max = 32 , count = 0
w = 10 , h = 1 , a = 10 , max = 9 , count = 1
w = 2 , h = 6 , a = 12 , max = 10 , count = 2
w = 4 , h = 2 , a = 8 , max = 12 , count = 0
w = 3 , h = 8 , a = 24 , max = 8 , count = 1
w = 4 , h = 7 , a = 28 , max = 24 , count = 2
w = 6 , h = 2 , a = 12 , max = 28 , count = 0
w = 10 , h = 3 , a = 30 , max = 12 , count = 1
w = 2 , h = 1 , a = 2 , max = 30 , count = 0
w = 2 , h = 5 , a = 10 , max = 2 , count = 1
w = 3 , h = 6 , a = 18 , max = 10 , count = 2
w = 5 , h = 3 , a = 15 , max = 18 , count = 0
w = 1 , h = 8 , a = 8 , max = 15 , count = 0
w = 4 , h = 8 , a = 32 , max = 8 , count = 1
w = 7 , h = 1 , a = 7 , max = 32 , count = 0
w = 9 , h = 6 , a = 54 , max = 7 , count = 1
w = 8 , h = 8 , a = 64 , max = 54 , count = 2
w = 7 , h = 5 , a = 35 , max = 64 , count = 0
w = 8 , h = 2 , a = 16 , max = 35 , count = 0
w = 4 , h = 6 , a = 24 , max = 16 , count = 1
w = 7 , h = 10 , a = 70 , max = 24 , count = 2
w = 5 , h = 7 , a = 35 , max = 70 , count = 0
w = 10 , h = 2 , a = 20 , max = 35 , count = 0
w = 1 , h = 6 , a = 6 , max = 20 , count = 0
w = 1 , h = 2 , a = 2 , max = 6 , count = 0
w = 6 , h = 7 , a = 42 , max = 2 , count = 1
w = 10 , h = 10 , a = 100 , max = 42 , count = 2
w = 4 , h = 7 , a = 28 , max = 100 , count = 0
w = 7 , h = 10 , a = 70 , max = 28 , count = 1
w = 3 , h = 5 , a = 15 , max = 70 , count = 0
w = 7 , h = 5 , a = 35 , max = 15 , count = 1
w = 6 , h = 1 , a = 6 , max = 35 , count = 0
w = 4 , h = 2 , a = 8 , max = 6 , count = 1
w = 3 , h = 3 , a = 9 , max = 8 , count = 2
w = 10 , h = 1 , a = 10 , max = 9 , count = 3
w = 10 , h = 2 , a = 20 , max = 10 , count = 4
====================================================================
Four rectangles of increasing area.
[8, 9, 10, 20]
```

##### EDIT

The above code does not include the rectangle that breaks the run of ascending areas, i.e. the rectangle whose area is lower than that of its predecessor. The below code includes it.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Proj2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int count = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int[] as = new int[4];
        while (count < 4) {
            int w = r.nextInt(1, 11);
            int h = r.nextInt(1, 11);
            int a = w * h;
            if (a <= max) {
                count = 0;
            }
            as[count++] = a;
            System.out.printf("w = %2d , h = %2d , a = %3d , max = %3d , count = %d%n",
                              w,
                              h,
                              a,
                              max,
                              count);
            max = a;
        }
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        System.out.println("Four rectangles of increasing area.");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(as));
    }
}
```

Output from a sample run:

```
w =  1 , h =  4 , a =   4 , max =   0 , count = 1
w =  9 , h =  8 , a =  72 , max =   4 , count = 2
w =  7 , h =  5 , a =  35 , max =  72 , count = 1
w =  4 , h =  5 , a =  20 , max =  35 , count = 1
w =  5 , h =  7 , a =  35 , max =  20 , count = 2
w =  5 , h =  2 , a =  10 , max =  35 , count = 1
w =  7 , h =  6 , a =  42 , max =  10 , count = 2
w = 10 , h =  6 , a =  60 , max =  42 , count = 3
w =  5 , h =  3 , a =  15 , max =  60 , count = 1
w =  6 , h =  4 , a =  24 , max =  15 , count = 2
w =  5 , h =  2 , a =  10 , max =  24 , count = 1
w =  3 , h =  2 , a =   6 , max =  10 , count = 1
w =  3 , h =  4 , a =  12 , max =   6 , count = 2
w =  3 , h =  9 , a =  27 , max =  12 , count = 3
w =  8 , h =  5 , a =  40 , max =  27 , count = 4
====================================================================
Four rectangles of increasing area.
[6, 12, 27, 40]
```

Comment: but it missed the 5th last rectangle with area `6` (add the rectangle to the array also if/after resetting `count`)

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried the debugging and thats what made it more confusing. The output looks correct, but, if you look at line 26 in your output from the sample run, a is 7, then goes to 15, then 24, 63. Even tho this is in ascending order and is 4 in a row, the loop continues.

Comment: @user85421 that depends if you want to include the rectangle which breaks the run of ascending areas or not. That is not stated in the question and indeed, the code in the question does not include that rectangle.

Comment: I kind of disagree: "*until 4 consecutive areas in ascending order are outputted*" and even "*it printed 5 areas*" (as part of the problem) and "the code in the question" probably is not doing what is intended (otherwise it would be a review question)

Comment: @andrewrios refer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77637828/java-while-loop-randomrect-method/77637985#comment136872846_77637985). So are you saying that the rectangle that breaks the run should be included?

Comment: https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem/view/cs1/exams/midterms/midterm4/randomRects

Comment: @andrewrios see second solution in my answer.